# Update table from results of querying 2 other tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, case

I have the following problem:
There is table `LIST` with 5 columns:

1. List item
2. product_id
3. refNo
4. part_number
5. quantity
6. state

There are around `100 000 rows` in this table. There is also table `part` and `history` and they all have `part_number` column.

Now I need to `update LIST.state column with value 1, 2 or 3 where LIST.refNo = some value`, depending on the result of the following situation:

```
If LIST.part_number does not exist in table part.part_number
    set LIST.state to 1.
If it does, if this part_number and corresponding date in history is less than a week,
    set LIST.State to 2. Else set it to 3.
```

I am using `postgreSQL`. Any help would be greatly appreciated. So far, I know how to use this simple `IF ELSE` statement:

```
DO
$BODY$
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT part_number FROM part WHERE refNo=7000) THEN

    ELSE 
        UPDATE LIST set state = 1
    END IF;
END;
$BODY$
```

**I think its not the best approach** because now I have to enclose this if with loop and since there are `over 200 000 rows in history table`, comparing one by one will be super slow.

Maybe I can first select values that exist in part table and do queries on them to get values from history?

Answer (score 2):

No plpgsql needed here.

#### For lots of rows at once:

```
UPDATE list l
SET    state = u.state
FROM (
   SELECT li.pk_col
        , CASE WHEN h.hist_date > (now() - interval '1 week') THEN 2
               WHEN p.part_number IS NULL THEN 1
               ELSE 2
          END AS state
   FROM   list         li
   LEFT   JOIN part    p USING (part_number)
   LEFT   JOIN history h USING (part_number)
   WHERE  li.refNo = <some value>
   ) u
WHERE l.pk_col = u.pk_col   -- insert actual pk column
AND   l.state IS DISTINCT FROM u.state;
```

Or, faster, but a bit more verbose without subquery:

```
UPDATE list l
SET    state = CASE WHEN h.hist_date > (now() - interval '1 week') THEN 2
                    WHEN p.part_number IS NULL THEN 1
                    ELSE 2 END
FROM   list         li
LEFT   JOIN part    p USING (part_number)
LEFT   JOIN history h USING (part_number)
WHERE  li.refNo = <some value>
AND    l.pk_col = li.pk_col   -- insert actual pk column
AND    l.state IS DISTINCT FROM 
       CASE WHEN h.hist_date > (now() - interval '1 week') THEN 2
            WHEN p.part_number IS NULL THEN 1
            ELSE 2 END
```

I am assuming the column `history.hist_date`, since you did not specify.

Replace `pk_col` with your actual primary key column(s). You did not specify.

You shouldn't be using [unquoted mixed case identifiers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) like `refNo`. Either use `refno` or `"refNo"`.

The last `WHERE` condition avoids empty updates where `state` already had the intended value. Omit if that can't happen in your case. Most of the time it's an improvement to performance people tend to forget.

For this to be fast you need indexes on the involved columns. PK columns are indexed automatically. You also need one for every `part_number`, for `list.refNo` and for `history.hist_date`.
*Ideally* you'd have a [multicolumn index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-multicolumn.html) on `history` like:

```
CREATE INDEX h_multi_idx ON history (part_number, hist_date DESC);
```

Would trump one index for each column in this case.

#### Simpler version for few rows

Another way is a correlated subquery - simpler for updating a single or few row:

```
UPDATE list l
SET    state = COALESCE((
   SELECT CASE WHEN h.hist_date > (now() - interval '1 week') THEN 2 ELSE 3 END
   FROM   part p
   LEFT   JOIN history h USING (part_number)
   WHERE  p.part_number = l.part_number
   ), 1)
WHERE  refNo = <some value>;
```

For lots of rows at once, correlated subqueries do not scale well.
Note that this updates the row even if `state` already had the intended value .

#### Update for comment

For duplicates on `(part_number)` in `history` and (assuming) **no** duplicates on `(part_number)` in `part` or `list`, here is one (of many possible) solutions:

```
UPDATE list l
SET    state = u.state
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (h.part_number)
          li.pk_col
        , CASE WHEN h.hist_date > (now() - interval '1 week') THEN 2
               WHEN p.part_number IS NULL THEN 1
               ELSE 2
          END AS state
   FROM   list         li
   LEFT   JOIN part    p USING (part_number)
   LEFT   JOIN history h USING (part_number)
   WHERE  li.refNo = <some value>
   ORDER  BY h.part_number, h.hist_date DESC NULLS LAST
   ) u
WHERE l.pk_col = u.pk_col   -- insert actual pk column
AND   l.state IS DISTINCT FROM u.state;
```

There may be more efficient ways. Depends on missing information.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer is super detailed and very helpful.
However I noticed that first query does not always give me the correct value. Probably its because I forgot to mention that history has multiple rows for the same part_number, and when I decide wether assign 2 or 3 to state value, I have to look at the latest entry in history table. So lets say if my part number in history has date 01/01/2010 and also 07/07/2013, I need my state value in list to be 2 . Is it possible to modify the first query so it works like that?

Comment: @user2083691: You really should have mentioned that, along with other details as I already hinted. For a question like this, table definitions including `PK` and `UNIQUE` constraints should be provided - like you get from psql with `\d table` - *in your question*, not in comments. And some sample values.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with three separate queries (I'm sure there is a way to do it in one, like Erwins answer) which updates all values based on the `ref no` at once.

Like this:

```
--First
UPDATE LIST 
SET STATE = 1 
WHERE NOT PART_NUM 
IN (SELECT PART_NUM 
    FROM PART) 
AND REF_no = 1000;
--Second
UPDATE LIST
SET STATE = 2
WHERE PART_NUM IN
         (SELECT PART_NUM 
          FROM HISTORY 
          WHERE age(TIME, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) > (INTERVAL '-7 days'))
AND REF_NO = 1000;
--Third
UPDATE LIST
SET STATE = 3
WHERE STATE NOT IN(1,2)
AND REF_NO = 1000
```

This is not very elegant but should get it done, cant be certain if it would be the fastest way either.

Here's the [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d674d/1)